# Paginated results in mongoose with filters on reference document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a user and post document as follow:

```
user: {
"name": "Test",
interests: [
  "Sports",
  "Movies",
  "Running"
 ]
}

post: {
 "title": "testing",
 "author": ObjectId(32432141234321411) // random hash   
}
```

I want to query posts and fetch all those posts with author have "sports", "Running" as interests and this will be a paginated query.

How can I do so in mongoose and if not what alternative shall I use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following approach though giving answer with async/await approach but I actually used it using promises.

```
const fetchPosts = async (req, res) => {
  //First find users having those interests.
 const users = await User.find({ 
    interests: {
     "$in": ["Sports", "Movies"]
    } 
  })
  .select('_id')
  .exec();

 // map over array of objects to get array of ids
 const userIds = users.map(u => u._id);

 // Then run an in filter on Post collection against author and 
 //userIds
 const posts = await Post.find({
   author: {
     "$in": [userIds]        
    } 
  }) 
  .limit(15)
  .skip(0)
  .exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pagination using limit and skip

```
var limit = 5;
var page = 0; // 1,2,3,4

return Model.find({
        /* Some query */
    })
    .limit(limit)
    .skip(limit * page)
    .exec().then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Try this

```
const findUser = (interests) => {
    return User.find({
        interests: {
            $in: interests
        }
    }).exec();
};

const findPost = (query, page = 0) => {
    const limit = 5;
    return Model.find(query)
        .limit(limit)
        .skip(limit * page)
        .exec();
};

var execute = async () => {
    const users = await findUser(["Sports", "Movies", ]);
    users.forEach(user => {
        user.post = await findPost({
            "post.author": user._id
        });
    });
    return users;
}
```

Comment: I'll be using Post model and interests is not a property on Post model schema its on user model.

Comment: you can give any query.

Comment: what's problem in this?

Comment: How can I get run query author.interests {$in: [
 "Sports",
  "Movies",
]}

When author is referenced object.

Comment: do you want pagination on author or post?

Comment: I want pagination on Post and fetch only posts with their author having interests in an array


    "select * from posts join authors on posts.author = authors.id where author.interests in ("Sports" , "Movies") something like this in mongoose and mongo db"

Comment: What I did is somewhat similar, I fetched users having those interests first and then ran a $in of mongo against author on Post Model like "author": { $in: [ randomId, randomId, randomId ] }
It achieved what I needed.
Thanks. though